# How to set security rules to prevent delete data in firebase?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase structure likes:

```
"ROOT": {
  "Group": {
    "User": {
      "Name": "",
      "Email": "",
      "Gender": "",
      "Mobile": "",
      "Time": ""
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I prevent user from running ref.remove() directly from client browser inspector which will delete all data without any prompt?

I want to allow client script to run firebase operations like

1. add/update data to /ROOT/, I mean, adding more "Group" child node,
   like Group2, Group3..., but can't delete this node.
2. and add data under /ROOT/Group/, as well as update and delete

How to setup the security rules? Thanks.

Comment: @Shilly, I doesn't matter if the ref is in the browser scope. Anyone can create a Firebase ref and call remove. You could also just send an HTTP delete request to root. You need to have server side security.

Comment: Ok then, thanks for the explanation. (post-delete :) )

Answer (score 6):

**Check out [Bolt](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html)!**

Bolt is a schema validation tool for Firebase.

So you could define your `Group` and `User` schema and then write rules to make sure no one who isn't authorized can delete it.

```
type User {
 Name: String;
 Email: String;
 Gender: String;
 Mobile: String;
 Time: Number;
}

path /group/$groupid {
  read() = true;
  write() = this != null; // don't delete existing data
}

path /group/$groupid/user/$uid is User {
  read() = true;
  write() = this != null; // don't delete existing data
}
```

Now you just need to generate the security rules from the command-line, or upload them using the Firebase CLI. Bolt doesn't have support in the dashboard just yet. You can also copy and paste the generated rules into the dashboard if needed as well.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much, David, I will look into that.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it works for you. If not let me know what's wrong. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: Seems like Bolt is not supported in firebase 3

Comment: @ZuzEL What makes you think that? From what I can find through search, it's still functional in the newest versions. (after all, it's only a compiler to a rules file; so even if the output had issues, you could fix those manually and then upload it)

Answer (score 3):

Some other helpful Bolt functions you can use:

```
path /create { write() { create(this) } }                                                                                                                                         
path /update { write() { update(this) } }                                                                                                                                         
path /delete { write() { delete(this) } }                                                                                                                                         
path /create-or-update { write() { create(this) || update(this) }}                                                                                                                

create(ref) { prior(ref) == null }                                                                                                                                                
update(ref) { prior(ref) != null && ref != null }                                                                                                                                 
delete(ref) { prior(ref) != null && ref == null }
```

See [this sample file](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/samples/create-update-delete.bolt) and it's [tests](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/src/test/create-update-delete-test.ts).